# Dynamic Dependent Drop down box not working using ajax in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm working on a dynamic dependent dropdown selection using Ajax

When I select the first column, the second one is always empty and not showing me the list of the `city`.

Controller code :

```
 public function  index  () {
        $ville=Vil::orderBy('Ville','desc')->get();         
        return view ('index',['vi'=>$ville ]);

public function delegation ($id)

    {
        $delegation = DB::table("delegation")
        ->where("ville_id",$request->ville_id)
        ->pluck("ville","id");
        return response()->json($delegation);
    }
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('delegation','specvil@deleg');
Route::get('/index','specvil@index');
```

Jquery code :

```
<script>

    $('select[name="Région"]').on('change', function () {
    var countryID = $(this).val();
    if (countryID) {
        $.get('/deleg/' + countryID, function (data) {
            $('select[name="ville"]').empty();
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                $('select[name="ville"]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
            });
        }, 'json');
    } else {
        $('select[name="ville"]').empty();
    }
    }):
    });         
</script>
```

The view :

```
<form action="{{route('ghof')}}" method="get">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <div class="from-box">
      <input type="text" class="search-field business" name="rech" value="" placeholder ="Cherchez..">
      <select type="text" class="search-field location" name="spec" id="s" value="spec" placeholder ="Spécialités">
         <option selected></option>
         @foreach($sp as $ss)
         <option value=" {{$ss->Spécialité}}"> {{$ss->Spécialité}}</option>
         @endforeach
      </select>
      <select type="text" class="search-field location" name="Région" id="Région" value="Région">
         <option selected></option>
         @foreach($vi as $vv)
         <option value="{{$vv->Ville}}">{{$vv->Ville}}</option>
         @endforeach
      </select>
      <select type="text" class="search-field location" name="ville" id="ville">
      </select>
      <button class="search-btn" type="submit" id="search"> Recherche </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

lets fix your select element
change

```
<select type="text" class="search-field location" name="Région" id="Région" value="Région">
```

to

```
<select class="search-field location" name="region" id="region">
```

in your controller

```
public function delegation ($id)
```

here you accept a variable ($id) so you need to fix your ROUTE

and change

```
->where("ville_id",$request->ville_id)
```

to

```
->where("ville_id", $id)
```

change

```
Route::get('delegation','specvil@deleg');
```

to

```
Route::get('deleg/{id}','specvil@delegation');
```

as you can see your route needs to accept a variable and always check route path with your Ajax path. you controller method name must be same as method name after @ character.

jquery:

```
$('select[name="Région"]')
```

to

```
$('select[name="region"]')
```

Comment: I get this error in the console `index.js:274 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined `

Comment: @ghofran I don't know what is in you js file. you need to check why "module" is not defined. in your "index.js" line 274. always track your code and watch the request life cycle in your code.